# Limit selectable Buttons in Angular Button Toggle Group

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular Material Button Toggle Group can be set to `multiple` and then from 0 to all buttons can be selected in the group.
Is there a way to force that at least one Button has to be selected and also set a maximum of selected buttons (if the limit is 2 and the user selects a third button, the first selected button should change to not selected).
Is it possible to achieve this with `mat-button-toggle-group`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must work with the property "value" of the group. In change method, pass the whole "group" using a reference variable.

e.g.

```
    <mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup" 
                   multiple=true (change)="change(group)">
      <mat-button-toggle *ngFor="let value of [1,2,3,4,5]" [value]="value">
        <mat-icon>format_align_left</mat-icon>
      </mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>
    <div class="example-selected-value">Selected value: {{group.value}}</div>

  max:number=2;
  change(group:any)
  {
     //group.value is an array with the elements selected
     if (group.value.length>this.max)
     {
        let newValue=group.value;
        newValue.shift();
        group.value=newValue;     
     }
  }
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6hdfgm?file=app/button-toggle-exclusive-example.ts)